# LINQ to SQL for tables across databases. Or View?

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a Message table and a User table. Both are in separate databases. There is a userID in the Message table that is used to join to the User table to find things like userName.

How can I create this in LINQ to SQL? I can't *seem* to do a cross database join.

Should I create a View in the database and use that instead? Will that work? What will happen to CRUD against it? E.g. if I delete a message - surely it won't delete the user? I'd imagine it would throw an error.

What to do? I can't move the tables into the same database!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A view will work, if you have granted access to both database to the configured user. You'll need to use the 2-dot notation. This will only work BTW if both databases are on the same server.

```
create view vwUserMessages as 
select * from db1.dbo.Users as users 
inner join db2.dbo.Messages as msg on msg.UserID = users.id
```

For CRUD: a view is (usualy) only for reading: do updates etc directly to the related tables, or use a stored procedure:

```
create proc pdeleteUserMessages (@UserID int) as

begin trans

delete db2.dbo.Messages where userid = @UserID
delete db1.dbo.Users where id = @UserID

commit trans

go
```

Comment: You can use views for CRUD operations by adding triggers to them. It's a bit dirty, but might do the trick.

Comment: I think I might use stored procs for create and delete then. It would be too much repetition to make another datacontext for Message table as well as the view... right? Or is there a nice way to combine the two?